# Why doesn't my nearby list show any Pokémons?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I play Pokemon Go my nearby list is just white and do not show any Pokémons at all, why?

Comment: Revoking my close vote because this asks about *a differant symptom*, but it is the exact same problem. ***Its not working, at the moment.***

Answer (score 2):

In my experience either there are no Pokemon nearby or the game didn't load properly (check that your experience bar is red and there are pokestops/gyms appearing around).

If it is the latter then try restarting and ensuring it loads properly, if it is the former then you will just need to go to a different location.

Comment: My experience bar is blue, and there are no pokestops nearby. The pokestops is maybe because I am not in a city.

Comment: @user156171 yeah I think that means it's not working, if your xp bar is blue. Try reloading the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are pokemons in those flying grass things that comes out on the GPS on your Phone.

Ahm leafes not grass, maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah!same thing was happening with me,and the experience bar will show red if you're in team valor and blue if team mystic...so it's nothing to do with that and the "nearby pokemons" not showing any pokemons is because you are probably in a rural place which has no pokestops and gyms...